# Filling limit of a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, limit

I'm trying to get my "loto" file filling up automatically but I'd like to have only 20 lines, so i try this code :

```
>loto
if [ -f loto ]
then
    nbligne=$(cat loto |wc -l)
    while [ $nbligne -lt 20 ]
    do
        echo $((RANDOM%1000)) >> loto
    done
    nbligne+=$(cat loto |wc -l)
fi
```

but the loop does not stop and the file is filled indefinitely

Comment: You should increment/update `nbligne` in the `while` loop :)

Comment: `+=` does not do what you think it does.  `+=` will do a *text string* concatenation unless you declared it as an integer with `declare -i nbligne`, in which case it will arithmetically add the value to itself.  However, you should only need to add one to it, so `(( nbligne++ ))` *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't changing the variable inside the loop, so the condition can never be false.

Maybe you just want to output 20 numbers?

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..20} ; do
    echo $(( RANDOM % 1000 ))
done > loto
```

Comment: damn why i havent think to do like you >< it more simple than my loop while !!